# Nested Tableview in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hello I'm using Corona sdk. I'm ok with tableview widget, but I need a nested tableview ("super rows and sub rows hidden  when I touch super row it's subrows are shown").

I attached two images to see what I need please help me with full code.

Like this:

[image]

Which was found: [Here](http://maniacdev.com/2012/07/open-source-custom-ios-control-for-creating-elegant-nested-table-views)

Or this

[image]

Taken which can be found: [Here](https://lh4.ggpht.com/Ub7v-DEGItW2NY9ymOjjESEgoZxhKZ-vuldyrXpzeUvhPMySTHa8R5Bcl4P01lCi0zE=h900-rw)

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. Please show what you have done so far and explain how well it works and what more you want it to do.

Comment: ok thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write your own table view?  Create a lua table filled with your values:

```
local table = {
[1]=hello
[2]=hi
}
```

Then just use a for loop to loop through all the values, and then increment the Y axis on each text object by 50 pixels?

```
for i=1,2 do
   display.newText(table[i],0,0+(i+20),native.systemFont,30)
end
```

You could easily do this without using corona widgets.  Just learn lua tables and for loops and your set.

Good luck!